# Gluon Mobile Toggle Button Jumping

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to implement a Gluon Mobile toggle button for a survey page, and when testing, the button jumps to the left a little when I click it. I don't want it to jump at all. You can see it here:

[image: Toggle button jumping]

Relevant code is here:

```
StackPane getToggler() {

    ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton("Yes");
    ToggleButtonGroup toggleButtonGroup = new ToggleButtonGroup();
    toggleButtonGroup.setSelectionType(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    toggleButtonGroup.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    toggleButton = new ToggleButton("Yes");
    toggleButton.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:steelblue;");
    toggleButton.setUserData("1");
    toggleButton.setSelected(false);
    toggleButton.selectedProperty().addListener((obv, ov, nv) -> {
        if (nv.booleanValue()) {
            toggleButtonGroup.setUserData("1");
        }
    });

    toggleButtonGroup.getToggles().add(toggleButton);

    toggleButton = new ToggleButton("No");
    toggleButton.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:steelblue;");
    toggleButton.setSelected(true);
    toggleButton.setUserData("0");
    toggleButton.setSelected(false);
    toggleButton.selectedProperty().addListener((obv, ov, nv) -> {
        if (nv.booleanValue()) {
            toggleButtonGroup.setUserData("0");
        }
    });
    toggleButtonGroup.getToggles().add(toggleButton);
    togglers.add(toggleButtonGroup);

    StackPane wrapper = new StackPane();
    wrapper.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    wrapper.getChildren().add(toggleButtonGroup);

    return wrapper;
}
```

Here's where I get the togglers and their relation to the label to the left:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this.questions.length; i++) {

        HBox row = new HBox();
        row.setSpacing(5);
        row.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        Label label = new Label(this.questions[i]);
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setPrefWidth(200);
        label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
        label.setFont(new Font("System", 14));

        StackPane wrapper = this.getToggler();

        Region region = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(region, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setHgrow(label, Priority.NEVER);

        row.getChildren().addAll(label,region,wrapper);
        box.getChildren().add(row);
        box.getChildren().add(new Separator());

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging, I've realized that the min width value of the toggle buttons is wider than their pref width.

This means that after the user selects one toggle, the min width is applied, and the control is resized with the required min width, shrinking the region as a consequence.

A quick fix (until this gets fixed in the control) can be setting the min width of your toggle buttons:

```
private StackPane getToggler() {

    ToggleButtonGroup toggleButtonGroup = new ToggleButtonGroup();

    ToggleButton toggleButtonYes = new ToggleButton("Yes");
    toggleButtonYes.minWidthProperty().bind(toggleButtonYes.prefWidthProperty());
    toggleButtonGroup.getToggles().add(toggleButtonYes);

    ToggleButton toggleButtonNo = new ToggleButton("No");
    toggleButtonNo.minWidthProperty().bind(toggleButtonNo.prefWidthProperty());
    toggleButtonGroup.getToggles().add(toggleButtonNo);

    ...;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.